# Number of ways of traversing a graph through all of its nodes?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, contest-math

> A lift has $N$ stops ($1,2,3,4,...,N$), hence have $N(N-1)$ distinct rides of travelling from floor $A$ to floor $B$ such that $A\neq B$. How many arrangements of these rides form a continuous trip that starts from floor 1 and ends at floor 1?

I was lost trying to solve it. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: isnt it just rearanging all the $n-1$ upper floors? so $(n-1)!$, no?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please review the [Meta Read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and enhance your question to provide your motivation/attempts.

Answer (score 0):

There are $N-2$ possible intermediate stopping points; at floors $2, 3, ..., N-1$.

Each one of these can either be chosen or not and so the total number of arrangements is $2^{N-2}.$